# Запятая между безличными предложениями

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

Ставится ли здесь запятая?
*Вечерело **и** холодало.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дискуссионный материал по данной теме на правах комментария

**1.  ПРАВИЛА 1956 ГОДА**

Как было указано в предисловии, Правила 1956 года  не являются учебным пособием для школьного преподавания, но должны использоваться при составлении всех учебных пособий и словарей. Материал там изложен очень кратко, в дальнейшем он был подробно разработан Розенталем и другими лингвистами. Но, как говорится, нельзя объять необъятное. Соответственно, **не все темы были рассмотрены в полной мере,** это касается и односоставных предложений.
http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/145-zap-19-25

**2. ПРАВИЛА РОЗЕНТАЛЯ**
http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:  5) **односоставные безличные предложения,** имеющие **синонимичные слова**: Необходимо рассмотреть авторские заявки и надо срочно составить по ним заключения.
Но при отсутствии синонимичных слов запятая между двумя безличными предложениями перед союзом и ставится: Нету чудес, и мечтать о них нечего (М.); Между тем совсем рассвело, и надо было опять выходить в море (Кат.);

**3. ПРАВИЛА ПАС ПОД РЕД. ЛОПАТИНА**
http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

В сложносочиненном предложении с одиночными союзами и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо запятая не ставится в следующих случаях:

4. если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой **безличные** или неопределенно-личные предложения **с одинаковой формой сказуемого**: С деревьев капало и вокруг пахло листвой; Зрителей разместили вокруг арены и на арену вывели участников представления;

**4.  КАК СТАВИТЬ ЗНАКИ ПРИ ОТСУТСТВИИ ЧЕТКИХ ПРАВИЛ**

(1) Итак, у нас нет обобщенного материала по всем односоставным предложениям при наличии союзов И, ИЛИ. Что можно сделать в таких случаях? Вероятно, следует **понять основную идею и применить ее к данной теме.** Запятая при наличии союзов И, ИЛИ не ставится между однородными членами и в сложных предложениях, если они тесно связаны и объединены в одну фразу, так что перечислительная интонация отсутствует.

(2) Односоставные предложения по структуре очень **близки к однородным членам**, но запятая там все-таки иногда ставится. Дело в том, что здесь требуется **полная однородность по всем показателям** (грамматическим и семантическим), а именно: одинаковая грамматическая форма, один производитель, одна ситуация.

(3) Для безличных предложений **это одинаковая грамматическая форма и одна ситуация.** При отсутствии подробных правил нужно особенно внимательно относиться **к практическому материалу**, изучать и собирать примеры из художественной литературы.

Мне приходилось разбираться с этой темой подробнее, чем обычно, и я могу предложить вам материал из своего личного конспекта (на правах обычных учебных пособий, каких сейчас много в Интернете). К сожалению, подробных официальных материалов по этой теме нет.

https://proza.ru/2021/01/14/1389

РАЗДЕЛ 7. ТЕМАТИЧЕСКИЕ ОСОБЕННОСТИ ПОСТАНОВКИ ЗНАКОВ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В ССП (более подробное рассмотрение некоторых тем)
Тема 3. **Особенности постановки знаков препинания в односоставных  предложениях** однородного и неоднородного  вида

БЕЗЛИЧНЫЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ

Безличные предложения являются предложениями однородного вида, если они выражены **одной формой сказуемого и называют одну и ту же ситуацию:**

(1) Однородный вид предложений: одинаковая форма сказуемого, одна и та же  ситуация, нет запятой:

Подпустить врага   и дать огонь по команде!
Промозгло  и мутно, туманно и вьюжно.
Меня сорвало с якоря   и понесло.
НЕОБХОДИМО рассмотреть авторские заявки и НАДО срочно составить по ним заключения (синонимичные слова).

(2) Неоднородный вид  предложений: разные формы сказуемого или разные ситуации, запятая ставится:

Уже совсем стемнело,  и начинает холодать.
Между тем совсем рассвело, и надо было опять выходить в море  Смеркалось,  и в комнате стало темно.
**Вечерело,  и становилось прохладно.**
В степи потемнело,  и с моря нагоняло низкие тучи.
Было тихо, светло,  и чуть подмораживало.
Небо заволокло тучами, и дождю конца не предвидится.
Нету чудес, и мечтать о них нечего.

**6. ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС**

А теперь сравним варианты:

(1) ***Вечерело и холодАло.*** (2) ***ВечерЕло,  и становилось прохлАдно.***

И вот решение получается разное. Ситуации похожие, но во втором примере разная форма сказуемых.  Очевидно также, что интонация вариантов тоже различается.  Соответственно, первый вариант мы можем однозначно приравнять к однородным сказуемым  и запятую не ставить.

Comment: Спасибо большое за, как всегда, обстоятельный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, так как глаголы однородны и у них одинаковая форма.

Там есть смысл в тире следствия, так как вечером холодает:
*Вечерело — и холодало.*

Правило Розенталя такое:
Если сказуемые двух безличных предложений вполне однородны по значению, то запятая перед неповторяющимся союзом *и (или)* не ставится, например:
*Необходимо проверить все письменные работы и надо срочно выставить отметки.

Не нужно злоупотреблять цеховой терминологией или же следует объяснять термины* (Горький).

Comment: Извините, я не нашла у Розенталя, на которого Вы ссылаетесь, такой формулировки: *если сказуемые двух безличных предложений вполне однородны по значению...* Есть другие рассуждения. Ссылочку на правило не дадите?

Comment: Здесь выражается не следствие, а две равноправные ситуации. Тире не нужно.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Нет, это из советской книги.

Comment: @Серж Тире не нужно, но возможно, если похолодало от наступления темноты.

Comment: @oleedd  А из какой советской книги, не сможете найти?  Интересно, какие безличные глаголы они считали однородными.  И это безличные предложения однородного типа или безличные однородные глаголы? Или сказуемые однородные?  Как-то не всё ясно с терминологией.

Comment: @Sharon Былинский, Розенталь "Трудные случаи пунктуации" (1959).

Comment: А можно  ее  почитать онлайн? Процитировать что-нибудь можете? Меня терминология для односоставных предложений интересует.  Былинский  был специалистом по стилистике и редактированию, а здесь же пунктуация, грамматика.

Comment: Там ничего больше нет (терминологии для односоставных предложений). Это первый справочник по пунктуации Розенталя. Ещё существует обновлённая версия 1961 года (у меня нет). Потом есть "Пунктуация для работников печати" (1972). Там всё то, что и в электронных справочниках (к сожалению, у Розенталя лишь одно пособие по пунктуации, которое просто переиздавалось). Только большой плюс в том, что в этих советских книгах Розенталя никто не правил.

Comment: Версия Розенталя в его правилах выглядит довольно странно, в ПАС и то логичнее. Значит, никакой другой конкретной информации о запятой в безличных предложениях нет. Я правильно понимаю?  Тогда уж лучше на Лопатина ссылаться.

Comment: Там рядом точно нет, иначе бы добавил в ответ. Мне тоже в ПАС понравилось.